# How to get any DOM Element by Ajax in PHPFox

Tags: phpfox

I thought i could use

```
$this->get('element_id')
```

to get the value of each DOM-Element in a Ajax-Function. But that doesn't work. Only Post-Elements i can get this way, right?
But how do i get other Elements?

Thanks for your help...

This is my Ajax-Class:

```
class Name_Component_Ajax_Folder_Ajax extends Phpfox_Ajax
{
public function test(){

    $iChildItemId = $this->get('element_id');
    var_dump($iChildItemId);
    $this->html('#testdiv', $this->getContent());
}
}
```

By clicking a link i call this function ( test() ) and i want to get the value of an input-field (elemnt_id)

Comment: Not enough info. Please show your javascript.

Comment: Ok take a look at my edit..

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have 2 common solutions to pass a value in an AJAX request that Web browse (Firefox, Chrome, ...) sends to server.

If you are using POST request, you should specific your expected value as a hidden input `<input type='hidden' id='val1' value='value_you_want_to_pass_to_sever'>`.

If you are using GET request, you can pass it by using URL param for ex: www.youserver.com?val1=value_you_want_to_pass.

You can get value you want to pass by using JQuery.

Then you can use $this->get('val1')  to get your value at server side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At this time i do it by GET-Request but i like to get it via POST.
Your second idea ($this->get('val1')) i've tested to (look at my post) but this doesn't work. The variable is every time "null".

Answer (score 0):

This should work to set an element:

```
$this->call('$(\'#js_photo_category_' . $aCategory['parent_id'] . '\').attr(\'selected\', true);');
```

The same can be used to get a value

```
$elementVal = $this->call('$(\'#js_photo_category_' . $aCategory['parent_id'] . '\').val();');
```

The best way is to use javascript in client side to get the id's using a foreach, save them in an array/json and send them in the request, then do something when done:

```
$.ajaxCall('module.function_name', 'arrayData='+myArray).done(function(data) {
        javascript_function(data);
    });
```

Hope this helps