# Is it possible & feasible to integrate new UI HTML design templates created using Bootstrap into a website developed in PHPFox? If yes how? If no why?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, phpfox

I've a social website like **'Facebook'** which is developed entirely in **[PHPFox](http://www.phpfox.com/)** version 3.0.7(a social networking platform created in php).

The website looks similar to **'Facebook'** and most of it's functionalities resembles the functionalities of **'Facebook'**.

Now to make the site looking better I want to integrate new HTML template designs that are developed using **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (front-end framework)**

I've few HTML pages developed by HTML designer using **Bootstrap framework**. Now I've to integrate those HTML templates into my website which is developed in PHPFox.

While doing so the existing functionalities of the website should remain intact. In other words, the current jQuery/AJAX functionalities should not be changed, they should also work with the new HTML design. Now here comes the major challenge for me. How should I avoid the conflicts between ids and classes which are already been used by current CSS/theme/jQuery/AJAX and the new ids/classes that would going to be applied from Bootstrap framework?
Anyhow ultimately already working functionalities shouldn't get affect.

I'm so much clueless about what appropriate approach should I follow to make this new UI design integration. There is not much information available in the [PHPFox Documentation](http://support.phpfox.com/) too. Even I don't know whether it's possible to do so or not.

If this new Bootstrap template integration can't be done please explain me in detail why?

How should I make this process of changing UI design smoother and easier? Using the already developed HTML templates am I following the wrong approach?

Also, currently there are two themes used in the website. What should be done to them when the Bootstrap template will be integrated into the website? How to manage these things since they are part of admincp panel of PHPFox?

Comment: You have to add the boostrap.css into your header, then adapt all the classes according the bootstrap docs

Comment: Bootstrap styles will no clash with your application styles. I guarantee it. If you need to clear your code from old styles, you will need to work hard on each your old template. I think there is no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize PHPFox theme as list here in [their documentation](http://support.phpfox.com/themes/managing-themes/). I don't think that I have to repeat all these information here. Starting from editing HTML, CSS, JS are mentioned in the documentation link I have provided. Also don't forget to refer following links. [Link1](http://www.phpfoxcamp.com/topic/6248-how-to-clone-the-default-phpfox-theme-and-create-your-own/), [Installing/Upgrading a Theme](http://store.phpfox.com/kb/article/66/installing-upgrading-a-theme), [Create a new theme](http://store.phpfox.com/kb/article/268/create-a-new-theme)

Or there are sites which you can purchase PHPFox themes.

## Update

http://store.phpfox.com/kb/article/221/mini-tut-basics-of-phpfox-ajax

[how ajax site wide browsing works on phpfox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559872/how-ajax-site-wide-browsing-works-on-phpfox)

[How to get any DOM Element by Ajax in PHPFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236962/how-to-get-any-dom-element-by-ajax-in-phpfox)

[phpfox , get value as response from an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996021/phpfox-get-value-as-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: First of all thanks for showing interest in the issue I'm facing. Actually, I know this but my scenario is different. There were PSDs and based on those PSDs HTML designer has prepared new HTML templates using Bootstrap framework. I've to make the website pages look similar to those newly designed HTML templates. There is no such thing like 'Theme' exist in my situation. So please show me the way.

Comment: Yes, Exactly 1st use a sample template to get an idea about the basic structure of the template in PHPFox. Then your HTML files can be divided and used. Please let me know exact place you have the problem

Comment: My main issue is with the implementation of jQuery and AJAX. How to do it? Nowhere on the internet I found a working example of it.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help but I don't want to buy a new theme. As I already mentioned I want to make the website exactly same in look and functionality as of the HTML template files which are designed using Bootstrap template. The JavaScript and AJAX functionality should also be according to the new templates.

Comment: You are getting it wrong. Above links show you how to implement AJAX in PHPFox

Answer (score 1):

There is a theme for **PHPFox** build in `Bootstrap 3.0`. You can have a try with that. Find the [demo URL here](http://macagoraga.com/demos/bootstraphpfox3/) and if you like you can purchase from [here](http://macagoraga.com/forum/store).